# Drawing cards from a deck in SciPy with scipy.stats.hypergeom

Tags: python, scipy, probability

I'm having trouble understanding [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html) for SciPy's `scipy.stats.hypergeom` functions. In my program, I consider various decks of cards and try to find the probability of various draws. The `hypergeom` class seems to have exactly this, but its documentation assumes a bunch of terminology knowledge that I don't have. Googling leads me to Wikipedia and Wolfram MathWorld, both of which assume that if you're asking about this kind of thing, you've read everything from the dang *Principia Mathematica* forward and just need a little refresher - so they're not actually helpful. Because this problem is "how do I apply this specific chunk of code to my problem?" I'm asking Stack Overflow.

I have a problem of the form "if you have a deck of *N* cards, *M* of which are the card of interest, what are the odds of having at least 1 copy of the card of interest in the top *Q* cards?" I also have a problem of the form "if you have a deck of *N* cards, *M* of which are the card of interest, how many cards must you draw from the deck to have a 90% chance of one of them being a copy of the card of interest?" The former problem is very close to the example problem given in the SciPy documentation, but it's not the same thing, and the list of methods is all jargon to me - I can't actually tell which of them is the one that I need. I also can't tell which method to use for the latter type of problem.

What do the methods of `scipy.stats.hypergeom` actually do, what are their arguments, and how can I apply them to my problems? Pretend I'm a moderately bright high-school student and not a mathematics PhD candidate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scipy.stats.hypergeom.pmf(k, M, n, N)
```

returns the probability that: from M cards, n of which are marked, if you randomly choose N cards without replacement, exactly k cards will be marked.

So you can get your desired answer (using your variable-names) by

```
def pick_Q(N, M, Q):
    """
    Given a deck of N cards, where M are marked,
    and Q cards are taken randomly without replacement,
    return the probability that at least one marked card is taken.
    """
    return sum(scipy.stats.hypergeom.pmf(k, N, M, Q) for k in xrange(1,Q+1))
```

(the sum of the odds that 1 card is marked, 2 cards are marked, 3 cards are marked... N cards are marked).

Luckily, there is a quicker way - the probability that at least one marked card is taken is the flip side of the probability that no marked card is picked. So instead you can do

```
def pick_Q(N, M, Q):
    """
    Given a deck of N cards, where M are marked,
    and Q cards are taken randomly without replacement,
    return the probability that at least one marked card is taken.
    """
    return 1. - scipy.stats.hypergeom.pmf(0, N, M, Q)
```

For your second question, there don't appear to be any functions that do what you want; however, you can start with

```
def how_many_to_pick(N, M, prob):
    """
    Given a deck of N cards, M of which are marked,
    how many do you have to pick randomly without replacement
    to have at least prob probability of picking at least one marked card?
    """
    for q in xrange(1, M+1):
        if pick_Q(N, M, q) >= prob:
            return q
    raise ValueError("Could not find a value for q")
```

**Edit:**

```
scipy.stats.hypergeom.cdf(k, M, n, N)
```

Given a deck of M cards, n of which are marked, picking N randomly without replacement, find the odds that *k or fewer* marked cards are picked. (You can think of this as the integral of .pmf)

Then .sf(k, M, n, N) is the flip side of .cdf - the odds that *more than k* marked cards were picked.

For example,

```
 k      pmf(k,52,13,4)   cdf(k,52,13,4)   sf(k,52,13,4)
     (exactly k picked)  ( <= k picked)   ( > k picked)
---  -----------------  ---------------  --------------
 0       0.303817527      0.303817527      0.696182473
 1       0.438847539      0.742665066      0.257334934
 2       0.213493397      0.956158463      0.043841537
 3       0.041200480      0.997358944      0.002641056
 4       0.002641056      1.000000000      0.000000000
```

**Edit2:**

actually, this gives another way of writing the pick_Q function - 'picking 1 or more marked cards' can be rephrased as 'picking more than 0 marked cards', so

```
def pick_Q(N, M, Q):
    """
    Given a deck of N cards, where M are marked,
    and Q cards are taken randomly without replacement,
    return the probability that at least one marked card is taken.
    """
    return scipy.stats.hypergeom.sf(0, N, M, Q)
```

Comment: Hey, awesome, that's helpful to me. Thank you! Upvoted. Can you add a layperson's explanation of what the other methods of the class do, especially `cdf` and `sf`?

Comment: The universe now makes more sense to me. Thank you. Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that this isn't a hard problem to solve without using `scipy` at all. Let's say we have a random permutation of 10 items:

```
4, 7, 2, 3, 0, 9, 1, 5, 6, 8
```

And a set of "winners" `2, 4, 6`. Since all we care about is winners and losers, we can simplify our representation a bit:

```
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
```

We can do the same with any set of 10 possible items and 3 winners; and given any possible permutation of the 10 items, we can perform the same simplification. So what's really happening is that each permutation "chooses" 3 winning indices, and the number of possible arrangements of winners in the deck is [10 choose 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), or `10! / (3! * 7!)`.

Now what we need to know is how many of those possible arrangements of winners give us at least one winner in the first `Q` cards. Since it's easier to calculate how many arrangements give us exactly *zero* winners in the first `Q` cards, we'll calculate that instead. So what we want, in the most concrete terms, is the number of sequences that look like this (for Q = 4):

```
0, 0, 0, 0 | 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0
```

Here we've partitioned the sequence, and the values preceding the partition should always be zero. How many such sequences are there? Well, there are exactly as many such sequences as there are sequences containing 3 winners in 6 cards. So that's 6 choose 3, i.e. `6! / (3! * 3!)`.

So to get the odds that in a random permutation of 10 values, the first three do not contain a winner, we simply calculate the following:

```
(6 choose 3) / (10 choose 3)
```

And to get the inverse odds, (i.e. the odds that at least one of the first three contains a winner), we do this:

```
1 - (6 choose 3) / (10 choose 3)
```

Generalizing, with `total` = `N`, `winners` = `M`, and `tries` = `Q`:

```
1 - ((N - Q) chose M) / (N chose M)
```

In python, that looks like this:

```
>>> def choose(n, x):
...     return reduce(mul, range(n, n - x, -1)) / math.factorial(x)
...
>>> def ntries_win_odds(total, winners, tries):
...     inv = (choose(total - tries, winners) / float(choose(total, winners)))
...     return 1 - inv
```

Solving in the opposite direction isn't too hard -- we just need an "inverse choice" function that solves `c = n choose x` for `n` given `c` and `x`. There's room for algorithmic improvement here, I feel, but this works:

```
>>> def choose_x_pseudoinverse(target, x):
...     for n in itertools.count(start=x):
...         if choose(n, x) >= target:
...             return n
```

Now, solving for tries:

```
odds = 1 - ((total - tries) chose winners) / (total chose winners)
(1 - odds) * (total choose winners) = ((total - tries) chose winners)
choose_x_inv((1 - odds) * (total choose winners), winners) = total - tries
tries = total - choose_x_inv((1 - odds) & (total choose winners), winners)
```

In Python, that's

```
def ntries_from_odds(odds, total, winners):
    inv_odds = 1 - odds
    tCw = choose(total, winners)
    return total - choose_x_pseudoinverse(inv_odds * tCw, winners)
```